# using animation_enabled boolean to prevent multiple jquery animations at once will break after being spammed

Tags: jquery

I have 4 links on my page which fade their respective divs in and out as well as adjusting the containing div's height where necessary. I only want one div on a page at a time and the onload visible div is labels_div.

When the user spams these links the divs get out of sync or overlap each other. I have researched this and the best possible option is to use a boolean variable which is checked onclick of each link.

The issue arises that when a user spams the links eventually the boolean value gets stuck on false thus preventing any more animations.

Could somebody explain what I have done wrong? Thanks

```
var animation_enabled;
animation_enabled = true;


function open_labels_div(){
    if(!animation_enabled )return;
    animation_enabled = false;
    if($("#labels_div").is(':hidden')){
        if($("#charts_div").is(':visible')){
            $("#charts_div").fadeOut(400, function(){animation_enabled = true;});
            $("#labels_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                $("#charts_div").css("display","none");
                $("#labels_div").css("display","inline-block");
            });
        }
        else if($("#blank_charts_div").is(':visible')){
            $("#blank_charts_div").fadeOut(400, function(){animation_enabled = true;});
            $("#labels_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                $("#blank_charts_div").css("display","none");
                $("#labels_div").css("display","inline-block");
            });
        }
        else if($("#reorder_div").is(':visible')){
            $("#reorder_div").fadeOut(400, function(){animation_enabled = true;});
            var minus = $("#reorder_div").height()-100;
            $('#tab_content').animate({'height': '-='+minus},400,"linear");
            $("#labels_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                $("#reorder_div").css("display","none");
                $("#labels_div").css("display","inline-block");
            });
        }
    }
}

function open_charts_div(){
    if(!animation_enabled )return;
    animation_enabled = false;
    if($("#charts_div").is(':hidden')){
        if($("#labels_div").is(':visible')){
            $("#labels_div").fadeOut(400, function(){animation_enabled = true;});
            $("#charts_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                $("#labels_div").css("display","none");
                $("#charts_div").css("display","inline-block");
            });
        }
        else if($("#blank_charts_div").is(':visible')){
            $("#blank_charts_div").fadeOut(400, function(){animation_enabled = true;});
            $("#charts_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                $("#blank_charts_div").css("display","none");
                $("#charts_div").css("display","inline-block");
            });
        }
        else if($("#reorder_div").is(':visible')){
            $("#reorder_div").fadeOut(400, function(){animation_enabled = true;});
            var minus = $("#reorder_div").height()-100;
            $('#tab_content').animate({'height': '-='+minus},400,"linear");
            $("#charts_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                $("#reorder_div").css("display","none");
                $("#charts_div").css("display","inline-block");
            });
        }
    }
}

function open_blank_charts_div(){
    if(!animation_enabled )return;
    animation_enabled = false;
    if($("#blank_charts_div").is(':hidden')){
        if($("#labels_div").is(':visible')){
            $("#labels_div").fadeOut(400, function(){animation_enabled = true;});
            $("#blank_charts_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                $("#labels_div").css("display","none");
                $("#blank_charts_div").css("display","inline-block");
            });
        }
        else if($("#charts_div").is(':visible')){
            $("#charts_div").fadeOut(400, function(){animation_enabled = true;});
            $("#blank_charts_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                $("#charts_div").css("display","none");
                $("#blank_charts_div").css("display","inline-block");
            });
        }
        else if($("#reorder_div").is(':visible')){
            $("#reorder_div").fadeOut(400, function(){animation_enabled = true;});
            var minus = $("#reorder_div").height()-100;
            $('#tab_content').animate({'height': '-='+minus},400,"linear");
            $("#blank_charts_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                $("#reorder_div").css("display","none");
                $("#blank_charts_div").css("display","inline-block");
            });
        }
    }
}

function open_reorder(){
    if(!animation_enabled )return;
    animation_enabled = false;
    if($("#reorder_div").is(':hidden')){
        var add = $("#reorder_div").height()-100;
        $('#tab_content').animate({'height': '+='+add},400,"linear", function(){animation_enabled = true;});
        if($("#labels_div").is(':visible')){
            $("#labels_div").fadeOut(400, function(){animation_enabled = true;});
            $("#reorder_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                $("#labels_div").css("display","none");
                $("#reorder_div").css("display","inline-block");
            });
        }
        else if($("#charts_div").is(':visible')){
            $("#charts_div").fadeOut(400, function(){animation_enabled = true;});
            $("#reorder_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                $("#charts_div").css("display","none");
                $("#reorder_div").css("display","inline-block");
            });
        }
        else if($("#blank_charts_div").is(':visible')){
            $("#blank_charts_div").fadeOut(400, function(){animation_enabled = true;});
            $("#reorder_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                $("#blank_charts_div").css("display","none");
                $("#reorder_div").css("display","inline-block");
            });
        }
    }
}

<div id='options_tabs'>
    <ul>
        <li onclick='open_labels_div()'><a>Labels</a></li>
        <li onclick='open_charts_div()'><a>Charts</a></li>
        <li onclick='open_blank_charts_div()'><a>Blank Charts</a></li>
        <li onclick='open_reorder()'><a>Reorder</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id='tab_content'>
    <div id='labels_div'>
        <p>labels content</p>
    </div>
    <div id='charts_div'>
        <p>charts content</p>
    </div>
    <div id='blank_charts_div'>
        <p>blank charts content</p>
    </div>
    <div id='reorder_div'>
        <p>reorder content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think the problem was that my animation_enabled = false; after calling the function was outside of the if statement checking if the div you want is or is not visible meaning it would set the boolean to false even if the div was visible.

```
function open_labels_div(){
        if(!animation_enabled )return;
        if($("#labels_div").is(':hidden')){
            animation_enabled = false;
            if($("#charts_div").is(':visible')){
                $("#charts_div").fadeOut(400);
                $("#labels_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                    $("#charts_div").css("display","none");
                    $("#labels_div").css("display","inline-block");
                    animation_enabled = true;
                });
            }
            else if($("#blank_charts_div").is(':visible')){
                $("#blank_charts_div").fadeOut(400);
                $("#labels_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                    $("#blank_charts_div").css("display","none");
                    $("#labels_div").css("display","inline-block");
                    animation_enabled = true;
                });
            }
            else if($("#reorder_div").is(':visible')){
                $("#reorder_div").fadeOut(400);
                var minus = $("#reorder_div").height()-100;
                $('#tab_content').animate({'height': '-='+minus},400,"linear");
                $("#labels_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                    $("#reorder_div").css("display","none");
                    $("#labels_div").css("display","inline-block");
                    animation_enabled = true;
                });
            }
        }
    }
```